# Django Try/Except CBVs dealing with query returning None?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to include some exception handling to handle queries that return `None`, If none is returned I just want to display a simple `JsonResponse` message. Working with FBVs, I've done this pretty simply. But when using class based views, my `except` block is not doing as I expect.

```
class BusinessDetailView(DetailView):


    model = BusinessDetail

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        business = self.model.objects.filter(**custom filters here)).values().first()
        logger.debug(Business: {business}')
        return business


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            try:
                business = self.get_object()
            except BusinessDetail.DoesNotExist:
                return JsonResponse({'Error': 'Business Does Not Exist.'})
            return JsonResponse(company, status=200)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f'Error getting business detail with error: {e}')
            return JsonResponse({'Error': 'Database error, return to previous page'}, status=500)
```

In the `get_object` method, the logger is returning `Business: None` as I expect. But in the `get` method, the `BusinessDetail.DoesNotexist` is not getting hit. The last `Try/Except` block is the one getting hit, returning `return JsonResponse({'Error': 'DB error, return to previous page'}, status=500)`.

From my understanding, the `DoesNotExist` exception would catch the query returning `None`? But in my case this is not occurring. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add `raise e` and post the output of the exception

Comment: You should use `.get(..)` instead of `.first()` to get a `DoesNotExist`.

Comment: Also it seems you have a typo in `logger.debug(Business: {business}')`. Maybe `Business` should be quoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding, the DoesNotExist exception would catch the query returning `None`?

**No**, `.first()` does *not* raise an error in case it can not find a record, in that case it simply returns `None`. This will thus *not* raise any `DoesNotExist` exception. There is nothing "special" about a `DoesNotExist` exception, this is just an exception like any other exception.

You use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) instead of `.first()` to get a `DoesNotExist`:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    business = self.model.objects.values().get(**custom filters here)
    logger.debug(Business: {business}')
    return business
```

Comment: Ahhhh. This makes sense. I was unaware of that! Thank you so much for the quick help and response!